# C++ Importing filename from variable

Tags: c++

I'm have variable 'filename' with contents 'code.h', i'm need do this,

```
#include <filename>
```

why it's not working? Or #include not works with variables?

Comment: [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you think you need this? Whatever is the actual problem you want to solve, this isn't the solution

Comment: `#include` is for other header files not variables. You should directly write `#include<code.h>`

Comment: You certainly can't include files at runtime, if that's what you're asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#include` is for other header files not variables. If you want to conditionally include header files you can use precompiler commands:

```
//config.h
#define USE_HEADER_CODE_H
```

```
//other.h
#include <config.h>

#if defined(USE_HEADER_CODE_H)
#include <code.h>
#else
#include <other_code.h>
#endif
```